# MVC - Send Class in Class To Controller with FormData

Tags: class, model-view-controller, subclass, form-data

I have 2 class. And Im using firts class in other class.

```
public class Adres
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Sehir { get; set; }
    public string Ilce { get; set; }
    public string Mahalle { get; set; }
    public string Sokak { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Adres UserAdres { get; set; }
}
```

I have this function in Controller

```
public ActionResult Kaydet(Users.User prm_query)
{
    int? ID = prm_query.ID;
    string UserName = prm_query.UserName;
    string Sehir = prm_query.UserAdres.Sehir;
    
   .....
}
```

When I post data  With JQuery I m using this code and its working good.

```
$.post("/Users/Kaydet",
{
  ID: 1,
  UserName: 'Emre',
  Password: '112233',
  UserAdres: { ID: 1, Sehir: 'Istanbul', Ilce: 'Kadikoy', Mahalle: 'Kemal', Sokak: 'Yok' }
},
function (Result) {

   // .....
});
```

But I want send this data with FormData and I m trying this but its not working.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('ID', 1);
formdata.append('UserName', 'Emre');
formdata.append('Password', '112233');
formdata.append('UserAdres', { ID: 1, Sehir: 'Istanbul', Ilce: 'Kadikoy', Mahalle: 'Kemal', Sokak: 'Yok' });

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Users/Kaydet',
   dataType: 'json',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   data: formdata
}).done(function (Result) {

   // ...

});
```

When I run this code, in Controller UserName, Password is coming but UserAdres allways coming null. How can I post this subClass with FormData?

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how to do it. If I write it as follows, it matches seamlessly on the Controller side. but I couldn't solve another problem I wrote below

```
formdata.append('UserAdres.ID', 1).val());
formdata.append('UserAdres.Sehir', 'Istanbul').val());
formdata.append('UserAdres.Ilce', 'Kadikoy').val());
```

but if the subclass is a list like below, I couldn't find how to add it into the formdata

```
public class User
{
   public int? ID { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public List<Adres> UserAdres { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this but it not worked, it didn't match on Controller side

```
$.each($('#cmb_modal_user_citys').val(), function (i, Item) { 
   formdata.append('UserAdres.ID', i).val());
   formdata.append('UserAdres.Sehir', 'Sehir-' + i).val());
   formdata.append('UserAdres.Ilce', 'Ilce-' + i).val());  
});
```